# Meteor, change in User profile structure leads to missing gravatar and no console.log errors

Tags: javascript, meteor, gravatar

I have users either uploading their image or if none, a gravatar is used.

In the original plan, everything works ok. Gravatar image is shown when there are no pics uploaded. I saved uploaded images url (cloudinary) under profile field, profilepicId.

**publish**

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find( {}, { 
        fields: { username: 1, profileImg: 1, emails: 1, md5hash: 1, profile: 1 }
    });
});
```

**The below is the user structure (original working code):**

```
username,
emails,
password,
profile : { profilepicId: {} }
```

**Registration of a new user (original working code):**

```
Accounts.createUser({         //thats all I can add based on docs
   username  : usernameVar,
   email     : emailVar,
   password  : passwordVar,
   profile   : { }

//and then to extend the user fields
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) { 
   if(options.profile) {
      user.profile = options.profile || {};
   }
   user.md5hash = Gravatar.hash(user.emails[0].address); 
   return user;
});
```

**Then in the html to show the image:**

```
{{#if profile.profilepicId}} 
   <a href="{{pathFor 'upload'}}" class="link">
      <img src="{{c.url profile.profilepicId format=format gravity='faces' mode='thumb' crop='thumb' width=60 height=60}}">
   </a>
{{else}} 
   <!-- the uploaded image --> 
{{/if}}
```

**And the Changes....**
So now, instead of saving the uploaded image in `profile: { profilepicId : {}}`, I save it outside of the `profile` field. I did not remove the default profile within Meteor user structure.

```
username,
emails,
password,
profileImg :{ social : {} , uploaded: {}}
```

**And the changes are reflected in Accounts.OnCreateUser:**

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) { 
   user.profileImg = { social : {}, uploaded: {} }
   user.md5hash = Gravatar.hash(user.emails[0].address); 
   return user;
});
```

The html for the uploaded pics will also change from `profile.profilepicId` to `profileImg.uploaded`. However that shouldnt matter since the gravatar which is not showing, does not require the line for upload html.

Thats all the changes i made. No changes to publish too. There are no error messages in the console log, and I narrowed down the missing gravatar to this change of user structure. Could anyone explain to me why this is so?

Comment: Do the desired fields exist in the documents on the server side? And on the client side (inspect it in the console)?

Comment: Hi, the desired fields are just empty arrays (before images are uploaded). Viewing through Savin Mongol package, the fields do exist. The md5hash field which was externally created also exists. However somehow user is undefined if i change the user info structure.

Comment: I am not clear on where the user is undefined. In addition, how are you storing the image URL once one has been uploaded (i.e, a method or trying to update the collection from the client)? I am not entirely clear on what *exactly* is wrong. Maybe it is the fact that now your `profileImg.uploaded` condition seems to always be true.

Comment: Ok so if uploaded image, it will be stored as a cloudinary URL in profileImg.uploaded. However Im not even uploading anything and the the gravatar is not appearing despite the existence of a md5hash.

Comment: but your template is checking `{{#if profileImg.uploaded}}`, which is true by the looks of it.

Comment: The `{{#if }}` returns true only if i uploaded something in the field. So if theres no upload, it returns false and shows gravatar instead. Anyway that part is working right. No issues. The problem is the gravatar isnt showing up and shows a blank space.

Comment: What makes you assume that? If I understand you changes correctly, the field is an (empty) object by default, and therefore truthy. BTW, I don't see any arrays anywhere (which you mentioned in a previous comment). If you can make it clearer, I would advise adding a current data sample and move of the template, markup output and expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all [you shouldn't use profile](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#dont-use-profile). The rest of the user document isn't writable for security reasons. So anything not in the profile field will not get written.

Consider profile as a separate profile collection on which you have full control, like in [socialize](https://github.com/copleykj/socialize-user-profile/).

Comment: Yes but if you read what I wrote ...the version thats working is the one that uses profile. I tried to change but its not working.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, profile field is writable, anything outside of it isn't writable to you unless you use specific functions provided by Meteor's accounts package. So once you put your profileImg field outside of the profile field it will be rejected by the server.

Comment: So what are the options if I cannot put it outside of profile, and I shouldnt use profile? cant move forward nor back! lol

Comment: You can use profile, but the recommendation is to create a new collection where you will store the user's profiles. Mine gets created via the socialize:user-profile package: https://github.com/copleykj/socialize-user-profile/blob/master/server/server.js

Comment: How is it that Im able to create a new field for md5hash but not the same for profile image? Docs are not helping much. I learnt only recently that `Accounts.createUser` cannot add fields, it has to be done on `Accounts.OnCreateUser`. In this case it has to be all in profile?

Comment: This answer is inaccurate and does not solve the OP's issue. The profile being writable by default can easily be patched if desired, nothing else makes it special (and you should do so even if you aren't using it). Any field can be added to the `users` collection from the server, via methods or other core API hooks like `onCreateUser`.